# C# Table Adapters adding extra delete queries after creating the adapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, tableadapter

I have a database table "Table A" and I have the stored procedures for various operations on that table, I tested them and they are working fine. 
I created a table adapter for this table in C# and the built was successfull,[I tried the Insert and select using the stored procedures we specify on this screen and it is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgEzC.png) 
Here is what I am unable to do: 
I want to add two delete queries that will delete certain rows from the DB through the TableAdpter RightClick> Add queries menu and I successfully added that and the build was successful but it just won't delete any rows from the table ! What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance !

[TableAdpter RightClick> Add queries menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MokKz.png)

Comment: Can you give us some of your code to see? It would be clearer if you did.

Comment: I don't have any code for that so far. I am trying to test the command using the right click Preview Data screen

Comment: You can't preview delete queries. Only queries that retrieve data can be previewed. The commands actually need to be executed for a preview, and doing that with a `DELETE` is obviously a bad idea, so Visual Studio won't do that. So... you'll still need code to call them.

Comment: So are you suggesting that it will work properly if I write the tableadpater code and do a tableadapter.tableblahdeleteBy(arg) ?

Comment: @JeroenMostert you are right ! thanks